# Changing input type password to input type text

Tags: jquery

I have an input type password that I want to change to text when an immage is clicked.

This is what I  did:

```
$('#txtGenerate').attr("type", "text");
```

But it's not working..
What can I do?

Comment: Some browsers don't really support changing the type of an `input` element. You should consider replacing the password input with a text input instead. From the [`.attr` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) (which you read, right?): *"**Note:** Attempting to change the `type` attribute (or property) of an `input` element created via HTML or already in an HTML document will result in an error being thrown by Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8."*

Comment: Works Fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm72s/)

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```
$('#txtGenerate').clone().prop('type','text').insertAfter('#txtGenerate').prev().remove();
```

1. [Clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the current input
2. Change the input type
3. [Insert](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) cloned input after old input
4. [Remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) old input

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yTudd/)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 $('#txtGenerate').prop('type', 'text');
```

Comment: Why should the OP try that? What's wrong with `.attr`?

Answer (score 1):

Use **[prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** instead:

```
$('#txtGenerate').removeAttr("type");
$('#txtGenerate').prop('type', 'password');
```