# In javascript type = "text"; not working in IE 8 and is working in IE 10+

Tags: javascript

In javascript type = "text"; not working in IE 8 and is working in IE 10+

Here is the Code:

```
function showAnsers() {
    //enter code here
    var ans;

    if (document.getElementById('displayanswer').checked == true) {
        <% for(int i=0; i<sd.getQuestionsCount(); ++i) { %>
            var ans1 = document.getElementById("_custom__answers" + <%=i%>).type = "text";
        <%}%>
    } else if (document.getElementById('displayanswer').checked == false) {
        <% for(int i=0; i<sd.getQuestionsCount(); ++i) { %>
            var ans1 = document.getElementById("_custom__answers" + <%=i%>).type = "password";
        <%}%>
    }
};
```

Comment: feel free to ask a question

Comment: IE8 SUCKS BRAH, don't use it

Comment: I order to make it work, you need to reconstruct the input. So, delete your input and append a new input. In IE is not supported to change input type. Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21303134/1057527).